# Switching context between two instances from one account

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have a server with two instances running on it (a dev environment) where we use one login to access either instance.  I wanted to be able to switch context from one instance to the other without changing my .profile to reference the other instance's db2profile, logging out and back in.  I wrote a script (iswap) to allow me to do that.  Here's what it looks like:

```
  if [[ $DB2INSTANCE = "instance1" ]]
  then
     . /usr/users/instance2/sqllib/db2profile
     echo "Switched context from instance1 to instance2"
  elif [[ $DB2INSTANCE = "instance2" ]]
  then
     . /usr/users/instance1/sqllib/db2profile
     echo "Switched context from instance2 to instance1"
  fi
```

If I do a "db2 list db directory" after running iswap it shows me the databases in the new instance.  If I echo $DB2INSTANCE it reflects the new instance.  But, if I do a "db2 list applications" it still shows me the applications connected to the original instance.   What am I not changing that I need to add to the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `list applications` command requires an instance attachment, which is performed implicitly when you first run this command against "instance1". The [CLP back-end process](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0010412.html) `db2bp`, which handles all server commands and SQL statements on behalf of the front-end program CLP `db2`, remains attached to the "old" instance after you switch the environment.

You need to end the back-end process by issuing the [`terminate` command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001973.html) (`db2 terminate`), which will cause a new back-end process to spawn and attach to the new default instance, as specified by `$DB2INSTANCE`, next time it is required.

Comment: Thank you. :-)   That does exactly what I want.